# What to set on Android/Windows laptop if I want to make them as slave?

Tags: bluetooth, laptop, android, windows, smartphones

I would like to control my Android smartphone/tablet or my Windows laptop using another Android/laptop or Arduino with HC-05 module. I want to control, such as, their volume, camera, microphone, and so on. Then *what do I need to set on my Android/Windows laptop so they are able to be controlled from another Android/Windows Laptop/Arduino with HC-05 Bluetooth module?* Here, the controlled Android/Windows laptop will become slave while the controlling Android/Windows laptop and the Arduino with HC-05 Bluetooth module become master. *"What do I need to set..."* here means that Android and Windows laptop normally nothing to set if they are as master. But probably need to set something related to the Bluetooth chip inside them to make them work as slave.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, it doesn't work that way. You would have to either:

1. Write an application for each of those platforms that *connects to* your bluetooth device, receives commands from it, and uses the appropriate OS features to perform those actions.
2. Make your device a Bluetooth HID device, and only do things that your phone/laptop/etc. support by default from HID actions (this probably includes volume up/down/mute, play/pause, and power controls, and maybe microphone mute/unmute, but probably not controlling the camera or anything very "advanced").

Comment: Are the ICs used in smartphone or laptop significantly different that in the Bluetooth module HC-05? HC=05 required setting to be as slave (0) or master (1) before they are used. Otherwise, they will not work.